# What's the relationship between the mass of a star and the mass of its core?

Tags: star, mass, core

What's the mathematical relationship between the mass of a star and the mass of its core?

For simplicity's sake, I'm asking about the cores of main sequence stars at birth, and by "core" I mean the part where fusion is happening.

I tried googling my question and found [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/relationship-between-stellar-mass-and-core-mass.947599/), but no one there actually gave helpful answers. There it was claimed that the Sun has a core that is only 35%, and Main Sequence stars have around 30% of the mass in the core, but no reasoning or citation for these values was given.

Comment: It's a good idea to repeat your question in the body of the posting.  You could also include what you understand the definition of "core" to be and any parts of the linked forum that you think could be relevant (an uncited answer is given there for main sequence stars)

Comment: Thanks. That should keep the mansplainers off my back.